# Hex color code used in XSLT is forming a different color code after generating excel

Tags: css, excel, xslt

I am using #003134 Hex color code in XSLT as below

```
<Style ss:ID="s2">
<Alignment ss:Vertical="Center"/>
<Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="14" ss:Color="#003134" ss:Bold="1"/>
</Style>
```

And I am calling it as:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
<Worksheet ss:Name="Summary">
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="33">
  <Cell ss:MergeAcross="1" ss:StyleID="s2">
    <Data ss:Type="String">My Company</Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
</Worksheet>
</xsl:template>
```

But After downloading excel, the color has changed to #003366

I tried most of the possible ways but couldn't fix it. Your help or suggestion on this would be appreciated.

Regards,

Raj

Googled it and also searched for many articles but did not get any solution. I tried in stack overflow and code project forums as well

Comment: Please explain how the first of your XML snippets is related to the second. I don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: "After downloading Excel"? We don't know enough about the processing you are doing to formulate any guesses about how downloading Excel could possibly affect that processing.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen - The first snippet is a stylesheet where as second one is the worksheet in which I am calling the Style ID "StyleID="s2" to apply the color for a particular cell

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a clarification. I believe this question has got nothing to do with [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt), I added [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).

When I open the following XML file with MS Excel

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="s2">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="14" ss:Color="#003134" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
  </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Summary">
    <Table>
      <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="33">
        <Cell ss:MergeAcross="1" ss:StyleID="s2">
          <Data ss:Type="String">My Company</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

then select the "My Company" text and choose "Font Color > More Colors > Custom", I see that the color is `#003366` in hex, not `#003134` as specified in the XML source.

Comment: Yes, this is what the problem I am facing. I would like to know why #003134 is getting converted to #003366. Any idea ?